# How to make int not apply if I input is a decimal

Tags: python

i'm a super ultra beginner and trying to learn and get a grasp on the basics. And i'm trying to figure out how to make it so that the int function doesn't apply if I input a decimal. How would you do it?

````
def google():
    return 'Just google it you fool'

def eq():
    return '='


try:
    cel = (int(input("Enter celsius: ")))
    fahr = (cel * 1.8) + 32


except:
    print("That's not a number")

    quit()
try:
    print(cel, "Celsius", eq(), fahr, "Fahreneheit")


except:
    print(google())```
````

Answer (score 1):

Rather than converting the user input to an integer, you can simply convert it to a float like this:

```
cel = (float(input("Enter celsius: ")))
```

This will serve your purpose for integer inputs as well as a decimal input.